# Having a List<T>, how can I get other fields from DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, list

I have a method named `GetOrders`. This method reads an XML file and gathers `OrderNumber` of  all orders related to a specific user. The method returns a `list<string>`.

Now I want to know, having my list, how can I get other fields of these OrderNumbers from DB?

Comment: language? platform? anything?

Comment: maybe add some code and expand on what you need to know, the question is currently very vague and people will battle to help you going on such little info.

Comment: -1 Poorly constructed question, more effort please.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Describe the database tables, the language and platform you're using, the actual difficulty you ran into...

Comment: @skaffman:
I use c# as the language and my application is web-based.

Comment: @Yuval: 
well, suppose that I have a table (table1) that has 2 columns: OrderNumber and OrderTitle.
Now, having OrderNumbers in list, how can I obtain OrderTitles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LINQ to SQL, it is trivial. I'll assume that you already have the designer-generated tables and your list (though why you're keeping it in XML is a curiosity, it seems more reasonable to keep it in the database as well).

```
 var orderNumbers = ... your list ...

 using (var dataContext = new OrdersDataContext()) // designer-generated context
 {
     var orderTitles = dataContext.Orders
                                  .Where( o => orderNumbers.Contains( o.OrderNumber ) )
                                  .Select( o => o.OrderTitle );

     ... now do something with the collection...
 }
```

Comment: could you please explain a little about your OrdersDataContext?

Comment: You probably need to read up on LINQ to SQL.  The DataContext is (typically) generated by the designer when you add a LINQtoSQL class to your project.  You can the use the server explorer to add tables from your database.  This results in autogenerated classes corresponding to the tables you add.  These are contained in the data context.  A good place to start is Scott Guthrie's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`GetOrders` needs to de-serialize the `Orders` into `Order` Objects and return these (not just the Order Numbers) So the `List` (Return Type) you want returned by `GetOrders()` is `List<Order>`.

e.g. `List<Order> orders = GetOrders();`

Then you can iterate through the Orders and get the other fields, e.g.:

```
foreach(Order order in orders)
{
   string orderNumber = order.OrderNumber;
   Guid id = order.ID;
}
```